# Check values from previous rows in Microsoft Access Table data validation rule

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-access

How can I create a data validation rule for Microsoft Access Table which will check the value from the current row with the value(s) from the previous row(s)?

Take the following table as an example:

**Table: Meter Reading**

| Date | Value | Remarks |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01-08-23 | 11111 | Ok |
| 02-08-23 | 22222 | Ok |
| 03-08-23 | 22333 | Ok |
| 04-08-23 | 22444 | Ok |
| 05-08-23 | 22555 | Ok |
| 06-08-23 | 22111 | Invalid entry. Present value should not be less than the previous one. |
| 07-08-23 | 22222 | Invalid entry. Present value should not be less than the previous one. |

For this table I'd like to implement the the following rule:

`if(present_value < max(previous_values), "Invalid Input")`

How to do this in an `ms-access` table?